# Angular - Extract response which is ProblemDetails type

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

In .NET Web API when any DataAnnotation attribute validation failed, it returns HTTP status code: 400 with the response as below:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-57b63f3ea418de93f36e991b5d8d2567-29a28274787dd62d-00",
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "A non-empty request body is required."
    ],
    "request": [
      "The request field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

This is a [`ProblemDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class as per MSDN.

Can someone let me know how to parse the `errors` part into an array of strings?

For example:

`errors` contain an array, whose item is a key-value pair.

```
{
  "errors": {
  "Field 1 Name": [
    "The request field is required."
  ],
  "Field 2 Name": [
    "The request field is required."
  ],
  .
  .
  .
  "Field nth Name": [
    "The request field is required."
  ]
}
```

How can I get these errors into the collection to show on UI for users?
I want to show it in toast as:

> "Key : Value"
>
> "Field 1 Name : The request field is required."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `catchError` rxjs operator to handle the response with the error status code.

Based on your sample API response, I extract the value from the `error` part, and convert it from the key-value pair (which is key: `string`, value: `string[]`), flatten the `value` to an array of objects with `{ field: string, error: string }` type.

And return the error Observable as `{ status: number, errorText: string, response: any }` type.

> Service

```
import { catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

submit(body: any): Observable<any> {
  // In real environment this is how you post request, get response and handle error response
    
  return this.http
    .post(API_URL, body)
    .pipe(catchError((err) => this.handleError(err)));
}

handleError(err: any): Observable<any> {
  let handleErrResponse = {
    status: err.status,
    errorText: err.message || err.errorMessage || err.title,
    response: err,
  };

  if (err.status == 400) {
    let errors = Object.entries(err.errors).reduce(
      (acc, cur: [string, string[]]) => {
        for (let err of cur[1]) {
          acc.push({
            field: cur[0],
            error: err,
          });
        }

        return acc;
      },
      [] as { field: string; error: string }[]
    );

    handleErrResponse.response = errors;
  }

  return throwError(() => handleErrResponse);
}
```

When the `Observable` is returned, trace whether the `status` is 400. If true, then you pass the formatted `response` to display the error messages as toast.

> Component

```
onSubmit() {
  let body = {};
  this.service.submit(body).subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
      // Success
    },
    error: (err) => {
      if (err.status == 400) {
        this.hasError = true;

        this.errors = err.response;
        // Use err.response to display in toast
      }
    },
  });
}
```

In my demo, I just display the formatted error response as an HTML template to prove the concept works.

```
<div *ngIf="hasError">
  <div *ngFor="let err of errors">
    {{ err.field }} : {{ err.error }}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o7cweg?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clearly explain